# Get the value from filter but got [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can help me for below code...why the result i got is [object Object]...

```
$('input:radio[name="item_request_status"]').filter('[value=2]').attr('checked', true);
alert($('input:radio[name="item_request_status"]').filter('[value=2]').attr('checked', true)); 
alert($('input[name="item_request_status"]:hidden').click().val(checkId).change());

var checkId = $('input[name="item_request_status"]:radio:checked').map(function() {
    return $("input[name='item_request_status']:checked").val();
}).get().join(',');
$('input[name="item_request_status"]:hidden').click().val(checkId).change();
```

Comment: Presuming you mean the `alert()` calls are returning `[object Object]` then that's correct behaviour. What are you expecting?

Comment: i expecting alert() returning value from radio button which is value=2

Comment: Then you need to call `val()` on that element with no arguments. You should also use `console.log()` to debug as `alert()` coerces data types